# Why can't [kepler] and Kepler get along?

Tags: discussion, tags

Will someone please elucidate why the tag [kepler](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kepler) is [not](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/9656) [on-topic](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/9645) [on a question](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/9668) on Kepler himself?

I am having some trouble understanding the inner workings of this community.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the situation correctly, your suggested edits have been rejected because they are too minor to be worth making an edit (and consequently bumping up an old question to the top of the "active" tab) for. This is normal on stack exchange. In particular, the rejection of your edit does not necessarily imply that the tag [kepler](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kepler) should not be used for questions about Kepler.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, only changing/adding some tags to an older question is too minor an edit. This is more acceptable if the question is new, or if you edit contains additional, more significant improvements.

Comment: I do not agree, completely, to this wording. Perhaps: 1. Those edits are _usually_ too minor… (but also quite often seen across network, with some regulars strongly disliking it akin to what you describe as 'normal') 2. This one was indeed not as complete as could be (eg: typo overlooked "conceivably") 3. Also depends on volume and status of edits/editors (re-tagging sprees should be self-limited to a few bumps in one day; & some users get carried away with such stuff (also leading to rejected edits if reviewers notice such behaviour))