# Do we have a recommended limit on edits per day?

Tags: discussion, editing

Having looked at the answer to this Q&A on the site

[Blacklisted [history] tag has reappeared](https://hsm.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/332/blacklisted-history-tag-has-reappeared)

I thought I would start to edit out the remaining [history](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history) questions. However I do not want to flood the home page so I was thinking of perhaps doing one every other day. I cannot find any consensus in this meta site on what the polite behaviour is, hence this question.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there is a consensus - do not make minor edits (at least not in bulk) to too old posts. And even if the edit is somewhat substantial, I would recommend not making too many of them as all of those old posts will be bumped. [Danu's comment](https://hsm.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/351/why-cant-kepler-and-kepler-get-along#comment673_353) to a related post describes what a minor edit is:

> As a rule of thumb, only changing/adding some tags to an older question is too minor an edit. This is more acceptable if the question is new, or if you[r] edit contains additional, more significant improvements.

However, removing the [history](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history) tag from old posts, in my opinion, is not a minor edit as the tag is supposed to be "burninated". Therefore, I welcome you to suggest edits to remove the tag but keep the number of suggestions low on a daily basis (maybe 1 to 2 edits per day). In fact, [I am also removing the tag](https://hsm.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/373/those-who-do-not-know-history-are-doomed-to-recreate-it#comment746_373).